# Solve equation: Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, warning-messages

I am trying to solve the equation below but it returns this error :Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD". I would be gratuful if you someone help to solve this equation.
[image: Here is a sceen shot of the code that i am using]

```
y = 16.2*10^15; 
t = 0.0835*10^15; 
nm = 10^(-9); 
a = 25*nm; 
c = 3*10^8; 
R = 75*nm; 
z = 2.25; 

F[x_, q_] := (1/R^3)*(-2*I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z]*R*(Sum[E^((I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z] + q)*R)/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}] + Sum[E^((I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z] - q)*R)/n^2, 
       {n, 1, Infinity}] + 2*Sum[E^((I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z] + q)*R)/n^3, {n, 1, Infinity}] + 2*Sum[E^((I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z] - q)*R)/n^3, {n, 1, Infinity}])); 


G[x_, q_] := (1/R^3)*(((x/c)*Sqrt[z]*R)^2*(Sum[E^((I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z] + q)*R)/n, {n, 1, Infinity}] + Sum[E^((I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z] - q)*R)/n, {n, 1, Infinity}]) + 
     I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z]*R*(Sum[E^((I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z] + q)*R)/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}] + Sum[E^((I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z] - q)*R)/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}]) + 
     (Sum[E^((I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z] + q)*R)/n^3, {n, 1, Infinity}] + Sum[E^((I*(x/c)*Sqrt[z] - q)*R)/n^3, {n, 1, Infinity}])); 

B[x_] := ((5.45 - 0.73*(y^2/(x^2 + I*x*t)) - z)/(5.45 - 0.73*(y^2/(x^2 + I*x*t)) + 2*z))*a^3; 

A[x_] := 1/(1/B[x] - ((x/c)*Sqrt[z])^2/a - ((2*I)/3)*((x/c)*Sqrt[z])^3); 

NSolve[1/A[x] - G[x, q] == 0, x]; 
NSolve[1/A[x] - F[x, q] == 0, x]; 

Plot[Im[x[q]], Re[x[q]], {q, 0, 1}];
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I am not too sure whether the answer to this other question is helpful but check [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178631/polynomialgcdlrgexp-exponent-is-out-of-bounds-for-function-polynomialgcd-erro?rq=1)

Comment: Let me advise you: remove all sub- and superscripts. Mma does not like them and using them in algebra often leads to errors. After you had removed these, it will be possible to look at your equation to to help you. Second, I hope you know that `\[Omega]p^2` is understood as a square of a single variable "\[Omega]p". Do not confuse it with `\[Omega] p^2` meaning "\[Omega]" times "p^2".

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the error the OP reports, but I can't solve the equation directly.  Here is the OP's original posting, which has now been changed:

```
nm = 10^-9;
a = 25 nm;
c = 3 10^8;
R = 75 nm;
z = 2.25;
S[w_, q_] := -2 I w/c Sqrt[z ] R (\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∑\), \(n = 1\), \(∞\)]
  \*FractionBox[\(Exp[\((I\ \ 
  \*FractionBox[\(w\), \(c\)] 
 \*SqrtBox[\(\(z\)\(\ \)\)] + q)\) R]\), 
 SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]]\)) + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∑\), \(n = 1\), \(∞\)]
 \*FractionBox[\(Exp[\((I\ \ 
  \*FractionBox[\(w\), \(c\)] 
  \*SqrtBox[\(\(z\)\(\ \)\)] - q)\) R]\), 
 SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]]\);


A[w_] := 1/(w - (w/c Sqrt[z ])^2/ a - (2 I)/3 (w/c Sqrt[z ])^3);
sol = NSolve[{1/A[w] - S[w, q] == 0, q ∈ Real, Re[w] > 0, 
Im[w] > 0}, w];
Plot[w /. Sol, {q, 0.1, 1}];
```

I can get a solution to the original equation with `NDSolve`:

```
wIC = FindRoot[1/A[w] - S[w, q] == 0 /. q -> 0,
  {w, 1 + I}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
(*  {w -> 1.64493 - 1.01468*10^-15 I}  *)

ndsol = First@ NDSolve[{D[1/A[w[q]] - S[w[q], q] == 0, q], w[0] == (w /. wIC)}, 
    w, {q, 0, 1*^8}];

Plot[ReIm[w[q]] /. ndsol // Evaluate, {q, 0, 1*^8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

*Response to comment:*
Integrating the differentiated equation produces a solution to the equation, if we start with an accurate initial condition `wIC`.  To get a more accurate interpolation from the integration, use `InterpolationOrder -> All`.  We can see that the result approximately achieves the precision/accuracy goals of a little less than `8` (i.e. relative/absolute errors of around `10^-8`).

```
ndsolA = First@NDSolve[{D[1/A[w[q]] - S[w[q], q] == 0, q], w[0] == (w /. wIC)},
    w, {q, 0, 1*^8}, InterpolationOrder -> All];
Plot[Abs[1/A[w] - S[w, q]] /. w -> w[q] /. {ndsolA} // Evaluate,
 {q, 0, 1*^8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

---

I'm not particularly interested keeping up with
[changing goalposts](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/handling-questions-and-associated-answers-when-question-is-fundamentally-changed).
But a quick check of the OP's new code gave nonconvergence warnings for the sums.  I got not `PolynomialGCD` errors in V11.3 (Mac) as reported by the OP, so it may be version dependent.

Comment: Why did you use NDSolve  instead of NSolve? That will change everything?

Comment: @ridha It changes the form of the output (as an `InterpolatingFunction` representing `w` as a function of `q`), but it's giving the solution to your equation by integrating its derivative.